# What’s the difference among connection, session and request in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As you know that there are three concepts in Sql Server:connection, session and request.

We can monitor them with `sys.dm_exec_connections, sys.dm_exec_sessions, sys.dm_exec_requests` system views.

Could you explain difference among them with samples?

Comment: [Tasks, Workers, Threads, Scheduler, Sessions, Connections, Requests – what does it all mean?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlmeditation/2012/12/13/tasks-workers-threads-scheduler-sessions-connections-requests-what-does-it-all-mean/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql) DMV includes user sessions as well as internal SQL Server sessions used to run background tasks. [sys.dm_exec_connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql) contains additional information for sessions established by external clients, including protocol details. [sys.dm_exec_requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql) contains information about active SQL Server requests (e.g. executing queries).

Run the queries below to see the information returned. Replace the outer joins with inner joins to better see the relationship cardinality.

```
--all sessions, including SQL Server system sessions
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s;

--sessions with client connections (including internal SQL Server system sessions that have no connection)
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS c ON s.session_id = c.session_id;

--sessions, including request info 
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS c ON s.session_id = c.session_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests AS r ON s.session_id = r.session_id
ORDER BY s.session_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Connection is Physical Communication Channel and Session is a state of information exchange. A Connection may have multiple sessions. A request is simply request to server for any kind of resource. You can request for resource once a session is established between you and server.

Comment: Hi - ref the Microsoft sourced article also posted above - "There is a 1:1 mapping between a Session and a Connection.".
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/tasks-workers-threads-scheduler-sessions-connections-requests/ba-p/333990